# How to show tooltip on Excel selected cell using Microsoft office js?

Tags: excel, tooltip, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

When I select the cell, open the tooltip on the selected cell. and content in a show like Formula, Some Text, etc. And using Microsoft Excel Add-in.

Search on Microshttps://www.microsoft.com/en-in/oft
R&D on this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office JavaScript API (OfficeJS) doesn't provide anything for displaying a tooltip in Excel. But you can add comments to the Excel workbook. The [Work with comments using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-comments) article describes how to add, read, modify, and remove comments in a workbook with the Excel JavaScript API. You can learn more about the comment feature from the [Insert comments and notes in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/office/bdcc9f5d-38e2-45b4-9a92-0b2b5c7bf6f8) article.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.